# "Rotate" objects to be added into an image in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

Sometimes I would like to add elements in pictures taken earlier, such as additional headgear on the heads of my friends. Unfortunately usually those objects do not have the same orientation as the target. Thus I tried different methods to match the orientations. Rotating the layer itself gives just a 2d-element, creating a 3d-element using PS CC creates a gray border, but is rotatable. Furthermore, this method significantly slows down processing when adding several objects.
Thus I was wondering if there are other methods to match the orientation of headgear (in that case) and head, without making it too obvious that it just is a 2d-layer, and without creating the obvious border & slowdown for multiple objects?

Answer (score 1):

To insert an object to a photo the new piece must be seen from the right direction. Very little can be done with warping and other distortion tools. They simply haven't the needed information for ex. how to change front view to left view. 3D model of the new object is the only possiblity if the wanted view isn't available as 2D image.

The right viewing direction isn' enough. In addition you must have

- right perspective; it's for the illusion of the same shooting distance with the same camera lens.
- same color balance
- same lights and shadows
- same general technical quality level: NOTE you can only detoriate.
- same orientation and scaling
- careful cut, anything extra in the seam reveals the truth
- no physical inconsistencies such as wrong bending direction or wrong light reflections

That's why plausible image manipulation is a demanding job. It's  still a form of handicraft, no automatic tools are available.

ADD: The demand of such tools is obvious because as information receivers people do not care what is true, only what seems to be true has some meaning. That contains also making a true photo intentionally seem to be manipulated and distributing it.